# Wrap text in tabular and itemize?

Tags: itemize, tabularx, wrap

I would like to get the following effect without manually using `&` and `\\` to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically)

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
% Make lists without bullets and compact spacing
\renewenvironment{itemize}{
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
}
}{
\end{list}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Main-Section}
\subsection*{Sub-Section}

   \begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}  
Title:             &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
TitleAgain:             &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `tabularx` environment and set the required width to `\linewidth`.  The text will wrap automatically in the `X`-column then.  Depending on your use case, a `description` environment can be more handy.  Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
% Make lists without bullets and compact spacing
\newenvironment{myitemize}{
  \begin{list}{}{
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
      \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }
  }{
  \end{list}
}

\usepackage{enumitem,tabularx,showframe,calc}

\begin{document}

\section*{Main-Section}
\subsection*{Sub-Section}

\begin{myitemize}
\item
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}lX@{}}
    Title:  & This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but
              you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a title,
              nobody but you know!  This is not a title, this is
              perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\tabularnewline
    TitleAgain:
            & This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody
              but you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a
              title, nobody but you know!  This is not a title, this
              is perhaps a title, nobody but you know! 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{myitemize}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont,labelindent=1.5em,%
  labelwidth=\widthof{TitleAgain:},leftmargin=!]
\item[Title:] This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but
  you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but
  you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but
  you know!
\item[TitleAgain:] This is not a title, this is perhaps a title,
  nobody but you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a title,
  nobody but you know!  This is not a title, this is perhaps a title,
  nobody but you know!
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you try aligning the table cells using the p (paragraph) mode?
e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
I would like to get the following effect without manually using ``\&'' and ``\textbackslash'' to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically).                                                  
    \hspace{1cm}
         \begin{table}[!h]
            \begin{tabular}{l c p{4in}} 
             \hline
             Title & &Title to the long Text cell\\
             \hline
             Title&:             &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!
                                 This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!
                                 This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
             TitleAgain&:        &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!
                                 This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!
                                 This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
             \hline
             \end{tabular}
            \caption{Solution: Text wrapped using the \texttt{p} (paragraph) alignment.}
         \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
% Make lists without bullets and compact spacing
\renewenvironment{itemize}{
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
}
}{
\end{list}
}

\newcommand{\wrapit}[2]{%
  \addvspace{\baselineskip}
  \parbox[t]{2cm}{#1\wrapdelim}%
  \hspace*{1em}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth - \parindent - 2cm - 1em\relax}{#2}%
  \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}
}
\newcommand*{\wrapdelim}{:}
% note: just as I defined '\wrapdelim', you could define lengths to make maintaining `\wrapit` more easy to control

\begin{document}

\section*{Main-Section}
\subsection*{Sub-Section}

   \begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Title:             &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
TitleAgain:             &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
                    &This is not a title, this is perhaps a title, nobody but you know!\\
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}


I would like to get the following effect without manually using ``\&'' and ``\textbackslash'' to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically).

%\newpage
\wrapit{Title}{I would like to get the following effect without manually using ``\&'' and ``\textbackslash'' to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically).}

\wrapit{TitleAgain}{I would like to get the following effect without manually using ``\&'' and ``\textbackslash'' to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically).}


I would like to get the following effect without manually using ``\&'' and ``\textbackslash'' to wrap the text (i.e., all the text will be wrapped automatically).


\end{document}
```